# Error list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

Tags: r, list, matrix, mean, covariance-matrix

I'm trying to get the "EvolvabilityMeans" (evolvability package) of covariance matrices from 14 species. First, I'm getting the list of covariance matrices and list of means (17 cranial distances). To test evolvability, I need to adjust the matrices according to the means. Remembering that all matrices are positive definite. The error appears when the evolvability means is calculated.

`

```
cov.matrices <- list(matriz.cov.1, matriz.cov.2, matriz.cov.3,
                     matriz.cov.4, matriz.cov.5, matriz.cov.6, matriz.cov.7,
                     matriz.cov.8, matriz.cov.9, matriz.cov.10, matriz.cov.11, matriz.cov.12,
                     matriz.cov.13, matriz.cov.14)

means.list<- list(Mean_1, Mean_2, Mean_3, Mean_4, Mean_5, Mean_6, Mean_7, Mean_8, Mean_9, Mean_10,  Mean_11,  Mean_12, Mean_13, Mean_14)

mean.std.matrices = function (cov.matrix, means){
  return(cov.matrix/(means%*%t(means)))
}

mean.std.cov.matrices <- list()
for(i in 1:length(cov.matrices)){
  mean.std.cov.matrices[[i]] <- mean.std.matrices(cov.matrices[[i]], means.list[[i]])
}
names(mean.std.cov.matrices) <- names(cov.matrices)

mean.std.cov.matrices

evolvabilityMeans(mean.std.cov.matrices, means = means.list)
list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

`

Comment: You are passing a _list_ of matrices and a _list_ of means to `evolvabilityMeans`. This function expects a single matrix as its first argument and a vector (or scalar) as its second argument. Does `evolvabilityMeans(mean.std.cov.matrices[[1]], means = means.list[[1]])` give you the correct output for your first matrix? If so, you might try `Map(evolvabilityMeans, G = mean.std.cov.matrices, means = means.list)` to get all 14 results in a single list.